# Why does where you declare function matter?

Tags: c, function, structure, prototype

So im just learning C but from my understand we can create Function Prototypes anywhere right?

So then when i was experimenting with function and structure why is it that. If i put the function prototype before the structure declaration is does not work but when i put the function prototype after the structure declaration it does work ?.

Could some kind soul explain this?

**Before structure declaration (Does not Work)**

```
/* Function Prototypes */
void printID(struct studentID person);

/* Structure Decleration */
struct studentID{
    char Name[50];
    int Age;
    int Birth_Year;
};


int main(){
    struct studentID me = {"BOB", 25, 1996};
    printID(me);
    return 0;
}

/* Function Details */
void printID(struct studentID person){
    printf("Your Name is %s\n", person.Name);
    printf("Your Age is %d\n", person.Age);
    printf("Your date of birth is %d\n", person.Birth_Year);
}
```

**After Structure declaration (Does Work)**

```
/* Structure Decleration */
struct studentID{
    char Name[50];
    int Age;
    int Birth_Year;
};

/* Function Prototypes */
void printID(struct studentID person);

int main(){
    struct studentID me = {"BOB", 25, 1996};
    printID(me);
    return 0;
}

/* Function Details */
void printID(struct studentID person){
    printf("Your Name is %s\n", person.Name);
    printf("Your Age is %d\n", person.Age);
    printf("Your date of birth is %d\n", person.Birth_Year);
}
```

Comment: C file is parsed in order. It's as simple as that. You can't use an ubdeclared identifier.

Comment: That's an obscure C feature called "function prototype scope". The first version simply doesn't declare `struct studentID` in file scope. The second version uses the one declared in file scope instead of declaring a new type. I'd say it may be considered a language defect, but it's here and it can bite one when writing code. (C++ changes this btw, the order doesn't matter)..

Answer (score 2):

Data types must be defined before you can use them.

Since `printID` has a parameter of type `struct studentID`, the definition of `struct studentID` must come before the declaration of `printID`.

C compilers process files in a single pass, so all types must be defined before they can be used, and all functions must be at least declared before they can be called.

A type definition must be *complete* before you can create an instance (object) of that type.  For `struct`, `union`, and `enum` types, the type definition isn’t complete until the closing `}`.

However, you can declare pointers to incomplete types; IOW, the following would be perfectly legal:

```
struct studentID;  // incomplete type definition

void printID( struct studentID *person ); 

struct studentID {
  ...
}; // type definition is now complete
```

You would still need the definition of `struct studentID` to be complete before you could dereference it in the body of `printID`, so you would have to put the body of `printID` after this.